# Highlight with the class on menu on different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is when I click on main menu or the sub menu the main menu element should be highlighted

In my example : if I click on Menu1 I should go to the index.php and the li should have class="selected"

And if I go to the Menu2Submenu1 I should go to the test.php and the li of Menu2 should have class="selected".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // Get current path and find target link
  var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
  
  // Account for home page with empty path
  if ( path == '' ) {
    path = 'index.php';
  }
      
  var target = $('li a[href="'+path+'"]');
  // Add active class to target link
  target.addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
li.selected {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-row bg-blue clearfix">
    <div class="page-position landmark">
        <ul id="topmenu" class="clearfix">
            <li style="width:8%;">
                <a href="index.php">Menu1</a>
                    </li>
            <li style="width:21%;">
                <a href="#">Menu2</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="test.php">Menu2Submenu1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Menu2Submenu2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
             </li>
            <li style="width:23%;">
                <a href="#">Menu3</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Menu3Submenu1</a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Menu3Submenu2</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target.addClass('selected');
```

add a class in the 'a' element not in the 'li' element.

or your css work only 'li' element

```
target.parent().addClass('selected');
```